# How to get notified when an Leaflet LayerGroup is shown or hidden?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, dom-events, onclicklistener

I want to get notified whenever the user clicks the "Cities" checkbox in the layer controls - which shows or hides the city markers in the [linked example](http://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control.html). Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g54efr69/) to play around with.

[image: Leaflet screenshot]

I saw that [*LayerGroup*](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#layergroup) derives some [events from *FeatureGroup*](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#featuregroup-click). Please correct me if I am wrong: As far as I understand showing and hiding the markers is not the same as [*layeradd*](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#featuregroup-layeradd) and [*layerremove*](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#featuregroup-layerremove)?!

The `input` element holds no `id` to bind to:

```
<label>
    <input class="leaflet-control-layers-selector" type="checkbox" checked="">
    <span> Cities</span>
</label>
```

How can I be notified when the markers' visibility is toggled?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use jQuery to select the input element, using its class:

```
$('.leaflet-control-layers-selector').click(function(){
    alert('something')
});
```

Furthermore, if you have more than one layer, you can check if the map contains one layer when you click one of the checkboxes.

```
$('.leaflet-control-layers-selector').click(function(){
    if(map.hasLayer(cities)) alert('something');
});
```

**UPDATE**

You can also use map events overlayadd and overlayremove, like this:

```
map.on({
    overlayadd: function(e) {
        if (e.name === 'Cities') alert('added');
    },
    overlayremove: function(e) {
        if (e.name === 'Cities') alert('removed');
    }
});
```

Here's an updated JSFiddle of your example: http://jsfiddle.net/pufanalexandru/g54efr69/1/